# How do I update an item within a list and maintain its index?

Tags: elm

How do I update an item within a list?

I tried the following:

```
setFeaturedLink links link =
    let
        dictionary =
            Dict.fromList links

        result =
            Dict.filter (\k v -> v.title == link.title) dictionary |> Dict.toList |> List.head

        index =
            case result of
                Just kv ->
                    let
                        ( i, _ ) =
                            kv
                    in
                        i

                Nothing ->
                    -1
    in
        if not <| index == -1 then
            Dict.update index (Just { link | isFeatured = isFeatured }) dictionary |> Dict.values
        else
            []
```

> The 2nd argument to function `update` is causing a mismatch.
>
> 59|                             Dict.update index (Just { link |
>   isFeatured = isFeatured }) dictionary
>                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Function `update` is expecting
>   the 2nd argument to be:
>
> ```
> Maybe
>     { contentType : ContentType
>     , profile : Profile
>     , title : Title
>     , topics : List Topic
>     , url : Url
>     , isFeatured : Bool
>     }
> -> Maybe
>        { contentType : ContentType
>        , isFeatured : Bool
>        , profile : Profile
>        , title : Title
>        , topics : List Topic
>        , url : Url
>        }
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> Maybe
>     { contentType : ContentType
>     , isFeatured : Bool
>     , profile : Profile
>     , title : Title
>     , topics : List Topic
>     , url : Url
>     }
> ```
>
> Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.

Is there a simple example of how I can update an arbitrary item within a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just `map` the links to links with updated value:

```
let
  updateLink l =
    if l.title == link.title then
      { l | isFeatured = True }
    else
      l
in
  List.map updateLink links
```

To be honest, I don't understand what `isFeatured` is in your code, but I assume you want to update it to True if link.title matches.

Comment: That is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple example of how I can update an arbitrary item within a list?

How about something like [this](https://ellie-app.com/3PsVGX5hh8qa1/1), which is loosely based on the code you've provided:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import List

type alias Thing = { title: String, isFeatured: Bool }

bar = (Thing "Bar" False)

things = [(Thing "Foo" False), 
         bar]

featureThing things thing = 
  List.map (\x -> if x.title == thing.title 
                    then { x | isFeatured = True} 
                    else x) 
           things

updatedThings = featureThing things bar

main =
  text <| toString updatedThings
  -- [{ title = "Foo", isFeatured = False },
  --  { title = "Bar", isFeatured = True }]
```

I should also note that if ordering is important, a more robust approach would be to add an index field to your record and sort the list if/when necessary.